# Is the $scope.$apply() call warranted for this scenario?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-digest

New to AngularJS (and JavaScript frankly), but from what I've gathered, explicit calls to $scope.$apply() are only needed when changes happen outside of angular's radar. The code below (pasted in from [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jb1I3c8ZmjOMmaJlkpTO)) makes me think it wouldn't be a case where the call is required, but it's the only way I can get it to work. Is there a different approach I should be taking?

index.html:

```
<html ng-app="repro">
  <head> 
    ...
  </head>
  <body class="container" ng-controller="pageController">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <tr class="table-header-row">
          <td class="table-header">Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="site-list-row" ng-repeat="link in siteList">
          <td>{{link.name}}
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs action-button" ng-click="delete($index)">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
var repro = angular.module('repro', []);

var DataStore = repro.service('DataStore', function() {
  var siteList = [];

  this.getSiteList = function(callback) {
    siteList = [ 
      { name: 'One'}, 
      { name: 'Two'}, 
      { name: 'Three'}];

    // Simulate the async delay
    setTimeout(function() { callback(siteList); }, 2000);
  }

  this.deleteSite = function(index) {
    if (siteList.length > index) {
      siteList.splice(index, 1);
    }
  };
});

repro.controller('pageController', ['$scope', 'DataStore', function($scope, DataStore) {
  DataStore.getSiteList(function(list) {

    $scope.siteList = list; // This doesn't work
    //$scope.$apply(function() { $scope.siteList = list; }); // This works

  });

  $scope.delete = function(index) {
    DataStore.deleteSite(index);
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() { callback(siteList); }, 2000);
```

This line will take you outside of Anglar's digest loop. You can simply replace `setTimeout` with Angular's `$timeout` wrapper (you can just inject it into your DataStore  service), and you won't need `$scope.$apply`.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` is `async` event which considered as out of `angular` context, so it doesn't run the digest cycle. You need to run it manually in when you do such thing but preferred one to use `$timeout`.

Instead angular does provide a `$timeout` service, which works as same as that of `setTimeout` but after executing a callback function it calls an `$scope.$apply()`

```
$timeout(function() { callback(siteList); }, 2000);
```

> Special thing about the `$timeout` is that it runs the digest cycle in
>   safer way. It gives you a guarantee that it will not conflict with any
>   currently running digest cycle. Behind the scenes, when you call function inside the `$timeout`, it checks whether there is any digest cycle running or not by checking `$scope.root.$$phase`, if it's in the `digest` phase, it places that digest cycle in queue and runs it after completion of that digest cycle.